# How I can show a message in angular?

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

I'm new in Angular and I'm using ngx-bootstrap date picker
I have a form with two date picker, so I want to show a message when two or one elements are empty  and someone clicks the button but I don't know how I can do that

Help me

This is my app.html

```html
<div class="container">
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>FECHA INICIAL: </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>FECHA FINAL: </label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Consultar</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

my component.ts

```html
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BsDatepickerConfig } from 'ngx-bootstrap/datepicker';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'prueba-datapicker';
  datePickerConfig!: Partial<BsDatepickerConfig>;

  constructor()
  {
    this.datePickerConfig = Object.assign({},
    {containerClass: 'theme-dark-blue',
    dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY'
    });
  }
}
```

this is the type of message I want to show (example)
[image]

Comment: let me see if I got this correctly. You want to show a validation message?

Comment: yes, I use swwetalert2